# failed to read file in dart

Tags: file, dart

I try to read file in dart but it does not work.

This is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('--- READ FILE BY LINES ---');
  File file = new File('w.txt');

  file.readAsLines().then((lines) =>
    lines.forEach((l) => print(l))
  );
}
```

This is the output:

[image: output]

I put the file in this directory:

[image: file directory]

This is the file content:

[image: file]

Comment: Are you running this in a web browser? `dart:io` isn't supported in web versions of Dart.

Comment: i just run F5 in vscode to run it

Comment: Your output says it is running "on Chrome in debug mode" which implies that this is begin run as a web script in some form.

Comment: is this because of i run it in flutter project? I try to run the file that is not in flutter project and it is work